# How to perform convolution with kernel bigger than image?

Tags: python, convolution, scipy

In [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27506/back-propagation-in-cnn) question I've seen an example of convolution by the kernel with the shape bigger than initial image's one:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

x = np.array([(0.51, 0.9, 0.88, 0.84, 0.05), 
              (0.4, 0.62, 0.22, 0.59, 0.1), 
              (0.11, 0.2, 0.74, 0.33, 0.14), 
              (0.47, 0.01, 0.85, 0.7, 0.09),
              (0.76, 0.19, 0.72, 0.17, 0.57)])

y = np.array([(0, 0, 0.0686, 0), 
              (0, 0.0364, 0, 0), 
              (0, 0.0467, 0, 0), 
              (0, 0, 0, -0.0681)])

gradient = signal.convolve2d(np.rot90(np.rot90(y)), x, 'valid')
```

So, we get this:

> array([[ 0.044606, 0.094061], [ 0.011262, 0.068288]])

I understand that `y` is flipped by 180 degress. But how does "valid" convolution work here? When we can get (2x2) shape from (4x4) convolved by (5x5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is your question how can we perform convolution operation with kernel bigger than input image?*

If **yes** then answer is [padding](https://machinelearningmastery.com/padding-and-stride-for-convolutional-neural-networks/). **TL;DR** you increase the size of the original image with boundary pixels so that kernel can "fit"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After padding, it appeared the result of convolution also needs to be rotated by 180°.